# prevent JMS printing stacktraces in the log file

Tags: java, log4j, jms, stack-trace

I have this Message-driven Bean implementation class in my project:

```
@MessageDriven(
    name="Updater",
    activationConfig = { 
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "topic/delete_topic"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "providerAdapterJNDI", propertyValue="java:/MyJMSProvider"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "reconnectAttempts", propertyValue=""+Integer.MAX_VALUE),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "reconnectInterval", propertyValue="15"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue=JbossJaasAuthenticator.principal),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue=JbossJaasAuthenticator.credentials)
        })
@Interceptors(MediaExchangeSpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MyUpdater implements MessageListener {...}
```

When my server is not reachable (which happens quite frequently), I'm getting this in my log file:

```
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation Unable to reconnect org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@28d79ac8(ra=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsResourceAdapter@6eff0db7 destination=topic/delete_topic destinationType=javax.jms.Topic tx=true durable=false reconnect=15 provider=java:/MyJMSProvider user=myuser pass=<not shown> maxMessages=1 minSession=1 maxSession=15 keepAlive=60000 useDLQ=true DLQHandler=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.GenericDLQHandler DLQJndiName=queue/DLQ DLQUser=null DLQMaxResent=5)javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: my.url.net:49227 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server my.url.net/10.0.9.60:49227 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server my.url.net/10.0.9.60:49227 [Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]]]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1763)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:693)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at org.jboss.util.naming.Util.lookup(Util.java:222)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.AbstractDLQHandler.setupDLQDestination(AbstractDLQHandler.java:106)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.AbstractDLQHandler.setup(AbstractDLQHandler.java:82)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.JBossMQDLQHandler.setup(JBossMQDLQHandler.java:48)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.setupDLQ(JmsActivation.java:413)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.setup(JmsActivation.java:351)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation.handleFailure(JmsActivation.java:292)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.AbstractDLQHandler.onException(AbstractDLQHandler.java:94)
at org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ConsolidatedRemotingConnectionListener.handleConnectionException(ConsolidatedRemotingConnectionListener.java:113)
at org.jboss.remoting.ConnectionValidator$1.run(ConnectionValidator.java:633)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server my.url.net/10.0.9.60:49227 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server my.url.net/10.0.9.60:49227 [Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:335)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1734)
... 13 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server my.url.net/10.0.9.60:49227 [Root exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:305)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:97)
at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:82)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:301)
... 14 more
```

I do use log4j. What do I need to do to only print out the first line of the exception, rather than the full stacktrace? Is there some JMS configuration that I need to tweak, or something that I can do in log4j?

Comment: Is the stacktrace produced by log4j?  If no, then changing log4j won't help.  If yes, then you should be able to change the logging properties to remove those (or all) stacktraces.

Comment: I don't have a specific configuration in the log4j for these classes, but on the other hand, the log file that the stacktrace is written to is defined in the log4j configuration. I only want to prevent the stacktrace from this exception, not from all the other ones. Let's say that log4j is responsible. What kind of log4j configuration changes should I do, to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: You can configure log4j to do log messages differently depending on the "Logger".  You could even implement and configure a custom Appender that treated different logged exceptions differently.